# Copy Omnikey shortcuts to another computer

Tags: macos, safari, search, safari-extensions

I use the [Omnikey](https://marioestrada.github.io/safari-omnikey/) extension on Safari 11.1, and find it very useful.  It allows immediate access to the search function on various websites through Safari’s address bar, merely by typing a keyletter or two; the user can specify both the sites searched and the keyletters. This dispenses with the intermediate step of navigating to the website to be searched, or even typing out the whole website URL in the search bar: the search occurs immediately upon the user’s entry of the site-choosing keyletter, the search term, and the return key.

I’d like to duplicate my Omnikey list of websites and keyletters on another computer. The net returns no info, and I’m not a programmer so the Git Hub link doesn’t help. Searching on the mac for the URLs in the Omnikey shortcut had no results.

Can any of you tell me where the data is retained, and how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Have you asked the Omnikey people?

Comment: Thanks, Steve: I didn't even consider that. Must be brain fade. I've just now emailed the developer.

Comment: The developer didn't respond. I copied each of the shortcuts and recreated the list manually on the second computer. It was tedious, but took only about ten minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The Omnikey developer finally responded. Omnikey data is kept within the folder located at ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage.